# Instgram browser text resizing issue

Tags: instagram

I finished up a website recently built on Squarespace and noticed that when you view it from instagram (where most traffic is coming from) the text resizes and scales on scroll.

I'm sure this is more specific to the Instagram browser window but has anyone found a fix or solution to this? Would love it if the text would just stay still.

Thank you in advance for any help!